# How to validate a payload in service class in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a Person pojo with some fields can't be null in MyGroup class.

```
 public class Person {
     @NotNull(message = "address not null", groups = { MyGroup.class })
     private String address;

     @NotNull(message = "groupId not null", groups = { MyGroup.class })
     private UUID groupId;

     private String name;
     private String phoneNumber;

     @Email
     private String email;
     private Boolean active;
}
```

I only want to validate the pojo when active = true, so I can't validate in the controller level.

I couldn't get the validation working in my service class:

```
 public class PersonService {
      @Validated(MyGroup.class)
      public PersonObject createPerson(@Valid Person p) { ... }

      public PersonObject updatePerson(Person p) { ... }
 }
```

In PersonsController where I invoked the service class

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@PostMapping
public PersonObject createPerson(@RequestBody Person payload) {
   if (payload.getActive()) {
       // want to validate the Not null fields
       return personService.createPerson(payload);
   } else {
       // does not need to validate fields 
       return personService.updatePerson(payload);
   }
}
```

I also couldn't get the email validation working properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you invoking your service class?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-from the controller calling the service method

Comment: _Code_, please, including how you're obtaining your instance of `PersonClass`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- updated

Comment: I think you should write your own validation class and let Spring do this job for you. The object should be fully validated before it arrives at your controller.

Comment: First, I will note that you _probably_ ought to be distinguishing your two cases by using separate POST and PUT request verbs. That said, however, you still didn't show how you're obtaining your instance of `PersonService`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Instances is autowired by spring-boot `@Autowired private PersonService personService;`

Comment: Presuming you're including `spring-boot-starter-validation` this *should* work.

Comment: @Matt-pow Can you try add `@Validated` at the top of the service classes; trying with and _without_ group class to see if any differences is made.